# Alphazero probabilities vector

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, chess

How does AlphaZero matches the probabilities vector, result of the output of the NN, with the possible moves? Doesn't the size of the vector of possible moves change through the game?

I was trying to build my own engine, but i really can't figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the AlphaZero does not match the probabilities to the moves that can be made, it doesn’t need to. AlphaZero’s policy head emits the probabilities of every move possible on a chess board (4,672 moves, using AlphaZero’s scheme), even if the move is illegal or the pieces required to make the move don’t exist. All the illegal moves are masked (their probabilities are set to zero) before the softmax is applied. From the paper:

> A move in chess may be described in two parts: selecting the piece to move, and then selecting among the legal moves for that piece. We represent the policy π(a|s) by a 8 × 8 × 73 stack of planes encoding a probability distribution over 4,672 possible moves. Each of the 8 × 8 positions identifies the square from which to “pick up” a piece. The first 56 planes encode possible ‘queen moves’ for any piece: a number of squares [1..7] in which the piece will be moved, along one of eight relative compass directions {N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW}. The next 8 planes encode possible knight moves for that piece…

In other terms, a move can be defined as picking a square, picking a direction to move in, and then picking the number of squares to move in that direction (if the direction is not a knight move). Every piece is seen as a sort of queen-knight super piece. I hope that answers your question.